# Why my smallest unix file descriptor number is 7 instead of 3 in terminal?

Tags: ruby, unix, ubuntu, file-descriptor

Accroding to 《Working with Unix Process》, I know that the smallest filedescriptor is 3, because 0, 1, 2 is allocated to ``` STDIN``STDOUT``STDERR ```.

But in ubuntu, I put code like this in a file:

passwd = File.open('/etc/passwd')
puts passwd.fileno

then I got `7` instead of `3`, if I just put code in irb, it is `9`.Is Ubuntu is something different? How can I get the 7 resources opened by ubuntu?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I highly doubt the file descriptor numbers are returned in order. Also, you could have other processes running that have open files. You can check this by running `lsof` in a terminal.

Comment: Why does it matter? You're supposed to think of file descriptors as opaque codes that just happen to fit in an integer.

Comment: @muistooshort I just want to confirm what the book says

Comment: The book is probably trying to say that you won't get a file descriptor of 0, 1, or 2 when you open your own file. The various run times will open their own files before your code gets run so you shouldn't expect to get 3. You'd probably have results closer to what you expect if you wrong a small C program that only used **open** and **write** and statically link it.

Comment: “The smallest _possible_ FD is _N_” is not by any means entailing “_N_ is to be the FD returned”.

Comment: POSIX(http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) says "The open() function shall return a file descriptor for the named file that is the lowest file descriptor not currently open for that process", and lots of programs rely on that. Refer to William's answer to see what the other descriptors are.

Answer (score 0):

To see which files any process has open, check in `/proc/XX/fd` where XX is the pid of the process you are interested in.  For the current process, you can look in `/proc/self/fd`.